# PHP form - how to direct user to specific page based on single drop down choice, AS WELL AS pre-populate target page withsome given inputs

Tags: php, html, forms, cookies

Bit of a weird one (for me at least...)

I want to have the user complete a small form in order to proceed with an application for two different types of finance (name, email, contact etc). The user is also required to specify the type of finance they would like, and submitting the form takes the user to the full application for that finance type.
I can already do this.

I also would like the input given in the initial form to be carried over to the full application.
I can do this also.

My problem is, I can't get both of these features working together at the same time!

Initial Form:

```
<form method="post" action="form.starterApp.php" name="applyStart" id="applyStart">
    <table class="applyStart formTable" style="margin-right:20px;">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <label for="ddAppType">Would you like to apply for Car Finance or a Logbook Loan?</label><br />
                <select name="ddAppType" id="ddAppType">
                    <option value="Car Finance">Car Finance</option>
                    <option value="Logbook Loan">Logbook Loan</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <label for="txtName">Your Name</label><br />
                <input name="txtName" type="text" id="txtName" value="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <label for="txtEmail">Your Email</label><br />
                <input name="txtEmail" type="text" id="txtEmail" value="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <label for="txtNumber">Your Contact Number</label><br />
                <input name="txtNumber" type="text" id="txtNumber" value="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="chkAge" class="chkAge">Are you over 18 years of age?</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkAge" id="chkAge" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Action Script (form.starterApp.php):

```
<?php
    if(!$_POST) exit;

    // Only edit below this line if either instructed to do so by the author or have extensive PHP knowledge.
    // Please Note, we cannot support this file package if modifications have been made below this line.
    $ddAppType      = $_POST['ddAppType'];
    $txtName        = $_POST['txtName'];
    $chkAge         = $_POST['chkAge'];
    $txtEmail       = $_POST['txtEmail'];
    $txtNumber      = $_POST['txtNumber'];

    $ifFinance  = 'apply-for-finance';
    $ifLogbook  = 'apply-for-logbook';


    //Setting the Application Type
    if ($ddAppType == 'Car Finance') {
        $appType = $ifFinance;
    }
    else if ($ddAppType == 'Logbook Loan') {
        $appType = $ifLogbook;
    }

    {
        header( 'Location: '.$appType.'' );
    }
?>
```

Target page:

```
<form method="post" action="form.fullApplication.php" name="applyFinance" id="applyFinance">
<table class="applyFinance formTable" style="margin-right:20px;">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <label for="txtName">Your Name</label><br />
            <input name="txtName" type="text" id="txtName" value="<?php echo $_POST["txtName"]; ?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <label for="txtEmail">Your Email</label><br />
            <input name="txtEmail" type="text" id="txtEmail" value="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <label for="txtNumber">Your Contact Number</label><br />
            <input name="txtNumber" type="text" id="txtNumber" value="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="chkAge" class="chkAge">Are you over 18 years of age?</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkAge" id="chkAge" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my first time posting on here, please forgive me if I have left out anything obvious and I will answer any questions as best I can.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can try registering the ddAppType in [session](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php) or in [cookies](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

Sessions and cookies let you register some values in some stage of the session and you can also retrieve them when you want (depening on the expiry time that you set for those values).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have considered cookies as a possible solution, but I'm not very experienced in using them. I also don't know much about sessions or how they work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would try doing some examples on Sessions or cookies, as these two are your only options!

Comment: Okay thanks - I'll look into these and try them out.

Comment: Very simple examples are http://us2.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php (for session) and  look at the examples in the Example section on this page http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: Great I'll look into this and post my results on here if I figure it out - thanks for your help!